# Why native .net 4+ string IndexOf is slower than that of .net 3-

Tags: c#, .net

Recently I tried to write a simple brutforce string search and compare it to the native .NET4 implementation in performance. However I was shocked because I got like x3 performance boost in certain scenarious with my custom method compared to the native .NET 4+ implementation. It all was tested in Release mode with different versions of .NET framework.

Somehow, .NET 4+ String.IndexOf was very slow. So I tested on old .NET 3- versions and have found that the native implementation is really faster than in latest .NET releases.

Here is the code: http://pastebin.com/GB5w7FXz

The gist of it is testing lots of runs of native method against my custom method:

```
private static int FindSubstringCustom(string text, string substring)
{
    int cachedTextLength = text.Length;
    int cachedSubstringLength = substring.Length;
    bool success = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < cachedTextLength; ++i)
    {
        if (text[i] == substring[0])
        {
            success = true;
            for (int j = 1; j < cachedSubstringLength; ++j)
            {
                if (text[i + j] != substring[j])
                {
                    success = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (success)
            {
                return i;
            }
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

I run it with Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition. Simple console application.

I still think that I made some very silly typo, but I'm unable to find it. It also doesn't help that my method returns correct results.

Comment: I cannot see your code from pastebin due to proxy restrictions, but keep in mind that the plain IndexOf method does a culture sensitive comparison - pretty expensive. Please consider posting your code as part of your question.

Comment: I just tested your code and can indeed see performance differences between version 3x of the Framework, versus version 4x.  Release x64, version 3 for standard library was about 42 ms for me, version 4.6.1 was about 176 ms.  No idea why mind you.

Comment: As the person above me said, IndexOf, the way you use it, does another internal calls each time to specify a culture. Maybe if you specify it yourself, it might save a little.

Wouldnt personally bother trying to optimize it just for a few milliseconds... yet if you really want to, use the native windows functions to get the index. It saves a lot of code that .NET does internally.

Look at the source code of CompareInfo.IndexOf for the specifics.

Comment: If you use Ordinal string comparison in the IndexOf method, you get a much quicker response on 4.6.1, of about 74ms, so over 100ms quicker.

Answer (score -1):

Your code is slower than the standard one on my machine (for both .Net 4, .Net 4.6.1, .Net 3.5) for 2 of the 3 tests (Release mode).

Also do note Microsoft's implementation does more things that take more time:

- they have a lot of input validation (to throw `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`, `ArgumentNullException`....etc.). This have an high impact of the tested code because it is litterally being executed thousands of times.
- they take the culture into account
- they have comparison options

For what it's worth, [here is their current implementation](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/775003a4c72f0acc37eab84628fcef541533ba4e/src/utilcode/newapis.cpp#L577). You can't really do better with your own code IMO.

Comment: Oh, now this is really strange, because I tested Release mode binary on 5 different machines unrelated to each other. This is really strange, because it indicates that all of my benchmarks, not only for this project, but also for lots of others were incorrect all this time? I understand that simple brutforce shouldn't be fast comparing to the native implementation which should use the most performant algorithms.